# Change Spotify apk name

Tags: android, apk, spotify, android-7.0-nougat

I'm trying to change the name of the apk of spotify, but show me many dependencies to make this...

First I follow this manual: [Change Package Names of APKs](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2760965)

1. On the first step, I found on

in manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.spotify.music" platformBuildVersionCode="24" platformBuildVersionName="7.0">
```

I modified by `com.spotify.jair`

3. On smali I modified the name of the folder `smali/com/spotify/music`
   to `Smali/com/spotify/jair`
4. Search `Lcom/spotify/music` and replace
   with `Lcom/spotify/jair` inside smali folder

After that, when I tried to install and the error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.spotify.jair attemptin
g to redeclare permission com.spotify.music.permission.SECURED_BROADCAST already
 owned by com.spotify.music]
```

I modified all the `com.spotify.music`, inside AndroidManifest.xml to `com.spotify.jair` and the error is:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /
data/app/com.spotify.jair-1: Can't install because provider name com.spotify.mob
ile.android.mediaapi (in package com.spotify.jair) is already used by com.spotif
y.music]
```

So inside: `res\values\` I found `<string name="media_provider_authority">com.spotify.mobile.android.mediaapi</string>` I modified: `<string name="media_provider_authority">com.spotify.mobile.android.mediaapis</string>`

And the error is:

```
6280 KB/s (35226422 bytes in 5.477s) Success
```

But the app does not open, and close inspected. Can anybody help me on the debug why the app is closing, Is there are a tool to debug why the app is closing?

**Thanks!**

Also to add this project tree:

[Project Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO88m.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, the app is crashing, you need to take a logcat to see why
adb logcat > l0g.txt
Open Spotify
Unplug phone
And then upload that to paste bin